# Push parameters from powerBi to Azure ML

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-machine-learning-service

I am planning to build a model in Azure Ml and there are certain parameters that needs to passed to the model ,before the model could be run.These parameters should come from PowerBi,maybe based on some filters . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI is not a datasource, it uses datasources for visualising data. I would rather have a strategy where you use the same data as the ones you're sending to PowerBI as a source for your ML models.

Comment: :that would be still fine , but my question was how do i send parameters to the model that i am building , say linear regression , i need to specify the dependent variable and also the independent varaibles.This should go to Azure from PowerBi based on filters .

Answer (score 0):

You can expose almost any parameters in AzureML as a web service parameter. 
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMgKJ.png)

You can then use PowerQuery to call the ML web service passing any user defined parameters. See this
[blog entry](https://rquintino.wordpress.com/2014/11/26/azureml-web-service-scoring-with-excel-and-power-query/)
on how to call AzureML from PowerQuery.